# pass json data to onclick jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to pass JSON object to onclick function but it does not work

```
              $.each(response, function(k, v) {
                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "   <td><a  onclick='showcomplaints('+ v.ID +')'  >" + v.ID + "</a></td>";
                    html += "   <td>" + v.Name + "</td>";
                    html += '  </tr>';
               });

            function showcomplaints(id)
            {
             alert(id);
            }
```

I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" in console window.

Comment: just concatenate the `v.ID` in the arguments the same way as you did in the text value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to fix this line in your code:

```
html += "   <td><a  onclick='showcomplaints('v.ID')'  >" + v.ID + "</a></td>";
```

As:

```
html += "   <td><a  onclick='showcomplaints("+v.ID+")'  >" + v.ID + "</a></td>";
```

the reason for this is you are calling a function showcomplaints which requires id and instead of this you were passing a string v.ID

hope this helps you in future : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp